# jQuery mobile, detect when a user swipes image to the right

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application which I want the user to remove DOM elements (img's) by puting his finger on the image, and "taking" it to the right. How can I detect that? I have no source code to show since I can't reallly think of a technique.

I am using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap.

Note: currently I am testing on Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the jQM library you can see the swiperight event:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js

Does this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/dQ4bq/
- http://jsfiddle.net/dQ4bq/1/ ( show / hide )

JS:

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $('#theImage').remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to remove image</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <div id="theImage">
            <img src="http://web.tiscali.it/filemediaxtractor/albumingz/Example%20-%20Stay%20Awake.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```